# How to hide clear button Icon inside SearchBar control Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using xamarin forms `SearchBar` control. I want to remove clear `button` `x` icon without using custom renderer.

```
<controls:ExSearchBar
    x:Name="entrySearch"
    BackgroundColor="White"
    CornerRadius="6"                   
    BorderWidth="1"
    HeightRequest="45"
    Text="{Binding SearchText}"
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    Placeholder="search">
</controls:ExSearchBar>
```

This is  `ExSearchBar` control in shared project

```
public class ExSearchBar : SearchBar
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty ElevationProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Elevation), typeof(float), typeof(ExFrame), default(float));

    public float Elevation
    {
        get { return (float)GetValue(ElevationProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ElevationProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: It seems no way to make it hide without using custom renderer. You could have a check with [SearchBar documnet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.searchbar?view=xamarin-forms) and the source code about [SearchBarRenderer](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/5.0.0/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS/Renderers/SearchBarRenderer.cs). You will find that it shows clear icon defaultly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40725932/xamarin-ios-hide-cancel-button-from-search-bar
Please go through this link it might help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The situation you are describing is the exact reason why Xamarin Forms ships with the ability to create custom renderers. The forms team define the UI elements in abstract (seperate from their native implementation) and when there is a specific feature that is not defined in their API, you must go down to the platform level to change it.

You can also use an `Effect` to achieve the same result, I have provided a custom renderer for iOS & Android to show you how you would go about achieving the UI you desire:

**iOS:**

```cs
public class SearchBarButtonRenderer : SearchBarRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<SearchBar> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            Control.SearchTextField.ClearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Never;
        }
    }
}
```

*Really simple, just remove the clear button from the underlying `UITextField`*

**Android**

```cs
public class SearchBarButtonRenderer : SearchBarRenderer
    {
        private readonly Context _context;

        public SearchBarButtonRenderer(Context context)
            : base(context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<SearchBar> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                // Get Search Close Button Drawable
                var closeButtonId = Resources.GetIdentifier("android:id/search_close_btn", null, null);

                var searchEditText = Control.FindViewById<ImageView>(closeButtonId);

                // Get Close Button Drawable To Replace Existing Drawable
                var closeDrawable = GetCloseButtonDrawable() as VectorDrawable;

                if (closeDrawable is null) return;

                // Apply Transparent Color To Drawable (To Make Invisible)
                var buttonColor = Xamarin.Forms.Color.Transparent.ToAndroid();

                closeDrawable.SetTint(buttonColor);

                // Set Drawable On Control
                searchEditText.SetImageDrawable(closeDrawable);
            }
        }

        private Drawable GetCloseButtonDrawable()
        {
            return ContextCompat.GetDrawable(_context, Resource.Drawable.abc_ic_clear_material);
        }
    }
```

*A little bit of a fiddle, find the close button drawable and replace it with a custom styled drawable*

Comment: I stated in question, I don't need custom renderer. Ok np.  `ExSearchbar` control is again custom one. How to do with that.

Comment: You do need a custom renderer, there is nothing defined in the cross platform API that grants you the ability to change these properties. You need to implement this custom UI on each platform. My code shows the basic custom renderer in isolation, you can update your renderer accordingly 

Comment: You should write about delete/disable the close button. I can I apply white/tranparent color xaml itself.

Comment: Is this true across both platforms? on Android the `CancelButtonColor` will affect the X icon but on iOS it won't. You can use the iOS renderer to achieve this.